# If then statement to delete columns

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

New to VBA and trying to understand how to write an efficient code for data cleaning purposes.

I have a spreadsheet where my first step would be to remove entire columns with certain headers (about 25). I tried writing If Then statements for each header, but I find it only works on the first item, then I get error 424 (object undefined). I don't completely understand the VBA structure yet, so not sure how I can write this more efficiently

```
Sub DataCleaning()

    Set MR = Range("A1:ZA1")
    For Each Cell In MR
    If Cell.Value = "subject" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    If Cell.Value = "Study" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Delete
    If Cell.Value = "site" Then Cell.EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

This code will eventually have a series of additional steps as well, like relabeling headers and will be applied to more than 1 tab, so each header won't necessarily be found all the time.

Any help in structuring this better would be appreciated!!

Comment: You will want to use an indexed loop going backwards starting at the last column instead of a `For Each Loop` as you will run into problems with it skipping columns if you do it that way.

Comment: This is so helpful. I hadn't considered going backwards with the loop, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub DataCleaning()

    For i = 677 To 1 Step -1
        With Cells(1, i)
            v = .Value
            If v = "subject" Or v = "Study" Or v = "site" Then
                .EntireColumn.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This works!! So with the For line (i = 677 To 1 Step -1), do you start from the bottom and work up? How would I know to arrive at this?

Comment: Also... this sometimes give me Run-time error 13 - Type Mismatch. Any idea why?

Comment: @nahsn  Column **ZA** is also column **677**.  Type Mismatch may arise from an error in the first row cell.